# Why does select max from a column with querybuilder return an array?

Tags: php, symfony, mariadb

I'm trying to get the last contact of a user, here is the query:

```
public function dateDernierContact($utilisateur): ?Contact
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('MAX(c.dateFin)')
            ->andWhere('c.utilisateur = :val')
            ->andWhere('c.archive = true')
            ->setParameter('val', $utilisateur)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
```

And where I use it:

```
$dateDeb=strtotime($contactRepository->dateDernierContact($user->getId()));
```

Last, the error:

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Also I use Mariadb from wamp don't know if it could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOneOrNullResult()` returns a single row, which is still an array, even if it has only one column.

Use `getSingleScalarResult()`.